# A city or a geographical area with corners forming only 45, 90, and 135 degree angles.

Tags: geography

Not sure this is a proper historical question, more like geographic, but since I'm asking about both current and historical cities, here it is.

Preamble:

In the industry I work in we deal with certain geometrical shapes. Many designs have this nice feature that all shapes are rectangles and they always meet at 90-degree angles. The whole industry calls such designs "Manhattan" because much of Manhattan consists of rectangular blocks and streets/avenues there meet at 90 degree angles.

Recently a different kinds of designs become increasingly important. They consist besides rectangles of triangles and trapezoids with 45 degree angles that meet at 45, 90, or 135 degree angles. These designs naturally should be named somehow, analogously to Manhattan.

The question: are there / were there any well-known cities with corners forming only 45, 90, and 135 degree angles? The blocks may include octagons or 45-degree trapezoids, etc.

The only candidate that we have is Barcelona: the new part of that city consists of octagons and squares, and the streets in that part of the city often form the prescribed angles. Unfortunately, this applies only to a relatively small part of Barcelona...

Comment: Try Google map searches on cities like Fresno CA and nearby areas. The cities are about as geometric as geometric gets. Particularly the smaller ones whose street names are 1st street, 2nd street, etc.

Comment: The question seems hidden in the fourth paragraph, but take a look at the outline shared by Washington, DC, and Arlington, Virginia.

Answer (score 1):

No, *Manhattan* as it relates to 90 degree features is the only one of its kind - a geometric property that is named after the geographical layout of a city.

This definition comes from [*Manhattan distance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), which also has other names like *taxicab distance*, since it describes the actual distance it takes to travel between two points in a city like Manhattan by taxi.

The analogous metric that includes diagonals is known as [*Chebyshev distance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance), named after [a mathematician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pafnuty_Chebyshev). Also known as *chessboard distance*, as it describes the distance it takes a king to move to a position.

The only other geographically-named metric is [*Canberra distance*](https://blog.csiro.au/going-nuts-with-the-canberra-distance/), which has nothing to do with diagonals nor the geographical layout of Canberra. Its name comes from its inventors, who lived there.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not asking which geometric properties *are* named after cities; I'm asking for a suggestion how *to* name the described geometric property.